# Counter Not Resetting In JavaFX Program

Tags: java, javafx

This is a basic circle clicking game that I built. I cannot figure out why the hits counter is not resetting to 0 after clicking the reset button. The misses counter resets perfectly fine but the hits is not.

```
public class ClickingGameFX extends Application {
    private static final int CIRCLE_RADIUS = 25;
    private static final int PANE_HEIGHT = 400;
    private static final int PANE_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int MAX_MISSES = 5;
    private static final int MIN_DELAY = 1000;
    private static final int MAX_DELAY = 5000;
    
    
    private int hits;
    private int misses;
    private Circle target;
    private Text hitsText;
    private Text missesText;
    private Text gameOver;
    private AnimationTimer timer;
    private BorderPane pane;
    private ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean pauseGame = false;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            
            Pane root = new Pane();
            root.setPrefHeight(400);
            root.setPrefWidth(400);
            root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
            
            hitsText = new Text("Hits: 0");
            hitsText.setFont(Font.font(20));
            missesText = new Text("Misses: 0");
            missesText.setFont(Font.font(20));
            
            //Create hit and miss buttons
            Button pauseButton = new Button("Pause");
            pauseButton.setOnAction(new PauseClickHandlerEvent());
            
            
            Button resetButton = new Button("Reset");
            resetButton.setOnAction(new ResetClickHandlerEvent());
            
            HBox bottom = new HBox(50, pauseButton, resetButton);
            bottom.setPrefHeight(50);
            bottom.setPrefWidth(PANE_WIDTH);
            bottom.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
            bottom.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
            
            pane = new BorderPane();
            HBox top = new HBox(10, hitsText, missesText);
            top.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0));
            pane.setTop(top);
            pane.setCenter(root);
            pane.setBottom(bottom);
            
            timer = new GameTimer();
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                timer.start();
            }).start();
            
            
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    private class GameTimer extends AnimationTimer {

        private long lastSpawnTime;
        

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            // check if it's time to spawn a new circle
            if (now - lastSpawnTime >= MIN_DELAY * 1_000_000L) {
                // create a new circle and add it to the pane
                Circle circle = new Circle(CIRCLE_RADIUS, Color.RED);
                circle.setOnMouseClicked(new ClickHandlerEvent());
                pane.getChildren().add(circle);
                relocateCircle(circle);
                circles.add(circle);
             
                // set the last spawn time and reset the missed balls counter
                lastSpawnTime = now;
            }

            // move the circles and check for misses
            for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
                Circle circle = circles.get(i);
                circle.setTranslateX(circle.getTranslateX() + 5);
                if (circle.getTranslateX() > PANE_WIDTH + CIRCLE_RADIUS) {
                    // circle has left the screen, remove it and increase the missed balls counter
                    pane.getChildren().remove(circle);
                    circles.remove(i);
                    if (++misses >= MAX_MISSES) {
                        // end the game if the missed balls limit has been reached
                        endGame();
                        break;
                    } else {
                        // set a delay before spawning the next circle
                        lastSpawnTime = now + (long) (Math.random() * (MAX_DELAY - MIN_DELAY) + MIN_DELAY) * 1_000_000L;
                    }
                }
            }
            missesText.setText("Misses: " + misses);
        }

        private void relocateCircle(Circle circle) {
            circle.setTranslateX(-CIRCLE_RADIUS);
            circle.setTranslateY(new Random().nextInt(PANE_HEIGHT - 2 * CIRCLE_RADIUS) + CIRCLE_RADIUS);
        }

        private void endGame() {
            stop();

            // display the game over message in the center of the graphics pane
            gameOver = new Text("Game Over\nHits: " + hits + "\nMisses: " + misses);
            gameOver.setFont(Font.font(30));
            gameOver.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            gameOver.setVisible(true);
            HBox end = new HBox(10, gameOver);
            end.setLayoutX(125);
            end.setLayoutY(200);
            pane.getChildren().add(end);
            
            circles.clear();
            
        }
    }
    
    private class ClickHandlerEvent implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            Circle circle = (Circle) e.getSource();
            if (pauseGame == true) {
                return;
            }
            else {
            pane.getChildren().remove(circle);
            e.consume();
            hits++;
            hitsText.setText("Hits: " + hits);
            missesText.setText("Misses: " + misses);
            
            if (!circles.remove(circle)) {
                misses++;
                missesText.setText("Misses: " + misses);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private class ResetClickHandlerEvent implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        hits = 0;
        misses = 0;
    
            pane.getChildren().removeIf(node -> node instanceof Circle);
           
            if (gameOver != null) {
                gameOver.setVisible(false);
            }
            timer.start();
        }
    }
    
    private class PauseClickHandlerEvent implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            if (pauseGame) {
                // resume the game
                timer.start();
                pauseGame = false;
            } else {
                // pause the game
                timer.stop();
                pauseGame = true;
            }
        }
    }

    
    private void relocateCircle() {
        
        target.setTranslateX(new Random().nextInt(PANE_WIDTH - 2 * CIRCLE_RADIUS) + CIRCLE_RADIUS);
        target.setTranslateY(new Random().nextInt(PANE_HEIGHT - 2 * CIRCLE_RADIUS) + CIRCLE_RADIUS);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I also added two if statements in the ResetClickHandlerEvent class to print to the console if any counter is reset to 0, and the console prints "Misses counter reset to zero."

```
private class ResetClickHandlerEvent implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            
            if (hits == 0) {
                System.out.println("Hits counter reset to zero.");
                }
            if (misses == 0) {
                System.out.println("Misses counter reset to zero");
            }
            pane.getChildren().removeIf(node -> node instanceof Circle);
            if (gameOver != null) {
                gameOver.setVisible(false);
            }
            timer.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your reset handler without debug statements you set `hits` and `misses` counters to `0`, but you don’t set the value of `hitsText` or `missesText`. The missesText will get set during the animation timer execution, but hitsText won’t update until a circle is clicked.  You can use binding with properties to bind values together, or define a method that updates both the counters and associated text at the same time.  There may be other issues, I didn’t try this, I just scanned the code.

Comment: In case, the "game loop" updates the `missesText` but not the `hitsText`, so one value is rendered correctly and the other is not. In my opinion, the approach is not very successful. Use property binding to update the controls only when their values change, and in the "game loop" update the values of the corresponding properties.

Answer (score -2):

As pointed out by you in the handle method you need to add the following resetting logic which will yield you the correct result.

hits = 0;
misses = 0;

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the logic is already in the ResetClickHandlerEvent code version without the debug statements.